# Enyojs add a loader effect for ajax call until successful response

Tags: javascript, enyo

I m new in enyojs. I have succesfully made an ajax call for listing data. What i need now is loader effect until data is loaded from ajax call. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do something like use a Popup with a Spinner in it.  You can set a flag on your app/view when you begin the fetch:

```
this.app.set('fetchingData', true);
```

and set it to false in the callback.  Then have the Popup show while fetching.  you can set this up with a binding if you like:

```
bindings: [
    {from: 'app.fetchingData', to: '$.popup.showing'}
]
```